# Need help with an edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, controllers, action

I'm working on a roleplaying game character database app and I need some help.

I've got two models, Character and Statistic. Each Character will have one instance of the Statistic model, which is a table with 6 separate statistics. I've used a partial to render the Statistic form on the Character view, so I can create a new Statistic that is associated with that Character from the Character view. However, I can't edit the Statistic and I can generate more than one instance, which are both problems.

My questions are:

How do I code an edit action in the Statistic controller so that I can edit the instance of Statistic from the Character view? I also want this to over write any Statistic instance that is present, so that I don't end up with multiple sets of Statistics per Character.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's some code:

From the Statistic controller:

```
def edit
    @statistic = Statistic.find(params[:id])
end
```

From the Character view:

```
%= render "statistics/form" %
```

And the form this code renders:

```
%= form_for([@character, @character.statistics.build]) do |f| %<br />

div class="field"<br />
%= f.label :strength % <br />
%= f.text_field :strength %<br />
/div<br />

div class="field"<br />
%= f.label :dexterity %br /<br />
/div<br />

div class="field"<br />
%= f.label :constitution %<br />
%= f.text_field :constitution %<br />
/div<br />

div class="field"<br />
%= f.label :intelligence %<br />
%= f.text_field :intelligence %<br />
/div<br />

div class="field"<br />
%= f.label :wisdom %<br />
%= f.text_field :wisdom %<br />
/div<br />

div class="field"<br />
%= f.label :charisma %<br />
%= f.text_field :charisma %<br />
/div<br />

div class="actions"<br />
%= f.submit %<br />
/div<br />
% end %<br />
```

Comment: Sure can. Here's what I have for the edit action from the Statistic controller:

Comment: @bacchus Thanks, I quickly realized 600 characters weren't enough!

Comment: @bacchus Thanks for the edits. I added rails to the tags, as well.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding the question, but is the question that you can see the form, but can't actually save the changes? If so, then the issue is that the "update" action is where the changes are saved, and your form needs to do a "PUT" to the update method in order for the changes to save.

Comment: @normalocity No, I can save the changes. I have two problems I'm trying to solve. First, the form will generate multiple sets of statistics, when I really just want one. Second, I need a way to edit that set of statistics, rather than generating new instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also having some difficulty trying to figure out what you mean, but between your last question and this one, I think I may understand most of what you are having trouble with.

I'm going off the assumption that a 'statistic' is a single table row with columns for each of the 'stats' you are tracking.  If that is the case, this should about do it.

```
# character.rb
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :statistic
end

# statistic.rb
class Statistic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :character
end

# characters_controller
def show
  @character = Character.find(params[:id])
end

# characters#show.html.erb
<h1><%= @character.name %></h1>
<%= form_for @character.statistic do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <label>Statistics</label>
    <%= f.text_field :strength %>
    <%= f.text_field :dexterity %>
    ...
    <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>

# statistics_controller.rb
def update
  @statistic = Statistic.find(params[:id])
  if @statistics.update_attributes(params[:statistics])
    redirect_to character_path(@statistic.character, :notice => 'Updated stats'
  else
    redirect_to character_path(@statistic.character, :error => 'Could not update'
  end
end
```

I do think that things would probably be a lot simpler if the character table just had each of the stats directly on that table, so that the form could just be for a character, and you only create form elements on the show page for the stats.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! As far as making the statistics part of the character, I thought about it, but I'll have other elements such as combat abilities, skills, equipment, etc, and I didn't want to load all of these things into the character table. My thinking is that if I could figure out how to manipulate one additional model, I could extrapolate the code and use it for the others.

Comment: Makes more sense now to keep it separate if that is the case.